# JS countdown to specific day and time in while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, countdown

I'm trying to make a while loop in javascript, which will countdown to every Wednesday to 17:00 PM CEST. I need to get the output in unixtimestamp.
I tried to do this:

```
// seed date, (ANY past wednesday at 17:00)
    var seed = new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 5, 30, 17));
    var target;
     
    // miliseconds to the next upcoming wednesday 17:00
    function timeToTarget() {
        while (seed < new Date()) {
            seed.setDate(seed.getDate() + 7)
        }
        target = seed;
        return Math.floor(seed - new Date());
    }
```

But something is incorrect and I don't really know what. It's showing me some random day and time 34 years ago. Output should be next wednesday  12.07.2023 17:00 PM CEST.

It's for discord purposes.

Thanks for possible answers!

Comment: while loop is the wrong thing for the job. That is just going to lock up the browser and prevent the screen from updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you don't need `target` and you shouldn't be subtracting anything from it and no need for `Math.floor()`.

```js
// seed date, (ANY past wednesday at 17:00)
var seed = new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 5, 30, 17));
     
// date of the next upcoming wednesday @17:00
function timeToTarget() {
  while (seed < new Date()) {
    seed.setDate(seed.getDate() + 7)
  }
  console.log(seed);
}

timeToTarget();
```